# find_under_expand in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to move to VS Code, and really like many of the feature.
But I'm really missing one of the most powerful editing features of sublime text: find_under_expand

i.e. select word with cursor, the select all other concurrences of this word by hitting ctrl+d.

Is there a way to reproduce this behavior in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> : keyboard shortcuts, search for select all.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> adds the next match to the selection one-by-one.